# Whats the difference between strtok and strtok_s?

Tags: c++, c++11

And what is closest to "split" in other languages?

Why did they change it? when I try using it (nothing in particular) it says that it's "not safe".

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

Comment: Also, `strtok` is a pure C function which almost certainly isn't what you want if you don't understand how it works and why there're two versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _s (_secure) functions:
In the early 1990s there were a lot of issues with buffer overflows. If I recall correctly, one of the reasons was to add some size / length checking.

For splitting, I believe you are looking for something that will return some sort of array. If this is the case, I do not believe you will find it.
The following is how I parse the path to an application:

I define it like this:

```
template<typename TDataType>
std::vector<TDataType>
Tokenize(const TDataType &oSource, const TDataType &Delimiters)
{
    std::vector<TDataType> OutputVector;

    typename TDataType::size_type xPosLast = 0;
//  auto xPosCurr = oSource.find_first_of(Delimiters, xPosLast);
    typename TDataType::size_type xPosCurr = oSource.find_first_of(Delimiters, xPosLast);

    while(xPosCurr != TDataType::npos)
    {
        if(xPosCurr != xPosLast) { // Ignore empty.
            OutputVector.emplace_back(oSource, xPosLast, xPosCurr - xPosLast);
        }
        xPosLast = xPosCurr + 1;
        xPosCurr = oSource.find_first_of(Delimiters, xPosLast);
    }
    if(xPosLast < oSource.length()) { // Ignore Last.
        OutputVector.emplace_back(oSource, xPosLast, oSource.length() - xPosLast); // add what's left of the string
    }
    return OutputVector;
}
```

I use it like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> PathVec = oAH.Tokenize<std::string>(sArgs, "/");
```

I check it like this:

```
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = PathVec.begin(); it != PathVec.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << ", ";
}
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
```

On OSX the check results in:

```
Main()::Tokenize
Users, Thoth, Library, Developer, XCode, DerivedData, [AppNameAndID], Build, Products, Debug, [AppName].app, MacOS, [AppName]
```

I ended up with the above after some research about splitting paths and tokenizing. In the comment section of the header where Tokenize is defined I have:
References work from:
    - Evan Teran https://stackoverflow.com/users/13430
    - Marius https://stackoverflow.com/users/174650
    - Alec Thomas https://stackoverflow.com/users/7980
    - Shadow2531 https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697
    - Marco M. https://stackoverflow.com/users/140311
    - Pixelchemist https://stackoverflow.com/users/951423/pixelchemist
    - Alveko https://stackoverflow.com/users/565368/alveko